# Article Tags should be many to many or column with separator

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many

Having Website in which user can post an article with  10 tags max,
I searched about how to design the database : all was many to many relationship.

But I found it much easier to add article tags with `&` or anything... Like that : `c#&c++&c&db&syntax`.

Would it differ in queries or something ?

Comment: Should totally be many to many relationship and yes that would completely change the way you query. Try to read a little bit about data modeling best practices. In particular what we call 3rd normal form data modeling technic.

Answer (score 1):

### Get used to many to many relationships

They won't harm you (too much ;))

> but i found it much easier to add article tags with

Only "advantage" is not to get used to something new (but good).

Adding tag to article:

delimted field:

```
UPDATE Articels SET Tags = CONCAT(Tags, '&', NewTag) WHERE Article.Id  = 123;
```

m:n (many to many):

```
INSERT INTO ArticlesTags (ArticleId,TagId) Values (123,NewTagId);
```

For me m:n is even shorter than delimited.

Now try to sort the delimited field, delete one tag or count the number of articles per tag.
How do you want to prevent a tag assigned more than one time to an artikel? That needs a check with delimited. With m:n just create a multi-column unique index on ArticleId/TagId and the database won't allow insert the ArticleId,TagId combo twice.

Another impact is that you (almost) can't use an index on the delimited field as you need to filter for sth. like

```
WHERE Tag LIKE '%TagToFilter%'
```

but you can use an index only starting with the first character in field like:

```
WHERE Tag LIKE 'TagToFilter%' OR Tag LIKE 'TagToFilter'
```

The only more complicated is to show all articles tags.

delimited:

```
SELECT Tags FROM Articles;
```

m:n

```
SELECT
    Articles.Id
  , GROUP_CONCAT(Tags.Tag) AS ConcatTags
FROM
    Articles
    LEFT JOIN
        ArticlesTags
        ON
            Articles.Id = ArticlesTags.ArticlesId
    INNER JOIN
        Tags
        ON
            ArticlesTags.TagId = Tags.Id
GROUP BY
    Articles.Id
```

Another flaw in your approach, you store the tags strings instead of their primary key. That causes many updates if you change a tag (e.g. c-sharp to c#). With the PK stored as Foreign Key. One Update on the tag changes it everywhere.